# MySQL Multiple Table Query

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

The question with criteria:

[image: The question with criteria]

Any help with creating the SELECT statement that satisfies this criteria would be appreciated. The tables I believe are being use are as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `ClientID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `ClientName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Street` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`)
)

CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `ClientID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `ContactName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ContactPhone` char(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContactEmail` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`,`ContactName`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ClientContact` FOREIGN KEY (`ClientID`) REFERENCES `client` (`ClientID`)
)
```

Here is what I've got so far.

```
SELECT ClientName, contact.ContactName, ContactPhone, ContactEmail, count()
FROM client, contact
GROUP BY ClientName, ContactName, ContactPhone, ContactEmail
ORDER BY ClientName;
```

Additional Information:

```
CREATE TABLE `event_contact` (
  `ClientID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `ContactName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `EventCode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`,`ContactName`,`EventCode`),
  KEY `FK_EC_Event_idx` (`EventCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EC_Contact` FOREIGN KEY (`ClientID`, `ContactName`) REFERENCES `contact` (`ClientID`, `ContactName`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EC_Event` FOREIGN KEY (`EventCode`) REFERENCES `events` (`EventCode`)
)

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `EventCode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `EventName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EventDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ticket` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VenueID` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `ClientID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EventCode`),
  KEY `FK_Events_Venue_idx` (`ClientID`),
  KEY `FK_Events_Venue` (`VenueID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_Client` FOREIGN KEY (`ClientID`) REFERENCES `client` (`ClientID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Events_Venue` FOREIGN KEY (`VenueID`) REFERENCES `venue` (`VenueID`)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would list the details for each client's contacts:

```
SELECT client.ClientName, contact.ContactName, contact.ContactPhone, 
contact.ContactEmail
FROM client, contact
WHERE client.ClientID = contact.ClientID
ORDER BY client.ClientName;
```

A join needs to be used to connect the two tables to get every contact for each client.

Group By would not be used for this because Group By would only return one contact for each client. The question states: "List the details for each client's contacts."

Also, you are missing information. The question also ask for the number of events the contact has organized. I am guessing that should be another column in the contact table or possibly information in another table.

Below is the query using an explicit join.

```
SELECT client.ClientName, contact.ContactName, contact.ContactPhone, 
contact.ContactEmail
FROM CLIENT
INNER JOIN contact ON client.ClientID = contact.ClientID
ORDER BY client.ClientName;
```

Comment: You should update the answer to use explicit joins `INNER JOIN ... ON ...` instead of implicit ones. The former is clearer.

Comment: Thank you! Could the missing table(s) be one of the two I've added to the post?

Comment: Yes, the event_contact and events tables would need to be used to get the number of events the contact has organized.